# "Wrong FS type" when inserting external storage

Tags: usb-drive

I installed Ubuntu for the first time and when I insert  external storage, I keep receiving the following error message:

```
WRONG Fs type,bad option.super block on/dev/sdb1,missing codepage or helper program,other error
```

Comment: Probably the "external storage" was last mounted on a Windows system that had "Fast Boot" enabled. Windows' "Fast Boot" makes undocumented changes to the disk. Linux doesn't recognize this. Back to Windows, disable "Fast Boot", eject the disk.

Comment: Exactly how do you mount it ?

Comment: If you left Windows fast start up on, then drive can only be mounted read only. Plug back into Windows & remove fast startup/hibernation flag. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Similar to answer but with -ro parameter. `sudo  mkdir /media/windows` & 
`sudo mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sdXY /media/windows` Where sdXY is your drive X and partition Y.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lsblk` to list your available disks

Then, type `sudo mkdir /media/directory/to/make`

Lastly, `sudo mount /external/drive/location/name /media/directory`

Here's how mine looks:

lsblk lists `dev/sdb1` as my external HDD. So, I just:

`sudo mkdir /media/Backup`
and then
`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/Backup`

Hope this helps! I've yet to find a way to make this detect automatically each boot, but I believe the issue is with the Windows formatting of my 10TB. I'm not about to go and wipe it until I back it up to a secondary though!

Comment: thanks 

but after  i got the drive name (sdc1 ) and typed the the command
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/Backup

i get
'mount: /media/Backup: mount point does not exist.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.'

Comment: @SibusisoSIPHOSENTLENdlovu You have to do `sudo mkdir /media/Backup` first.
If you did, but it didn't work, maybe you created `/media/backup`, and it is case-sensitive.